# Cases where Heaviside cover up method fails for partial fraction expansion.

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

Why can't I use Heaviside coverup method to find partial fraction expansion of:

$$F(s) = \frac{s^3}{(s^2+1)^2}$$

For example:

$$F(s) = \frac{s^3}{(s^2+1)^2} = \frac{r_1}{(s^2+1)^2} + \frac{r_2}{(s^2+1)}$$

$$r_1 = (s-\alpha)^r~ F(s) ~\bigg|_{s=\alpha}$$

$$r_1= s^3 \bigg|_{s=-1} = -1$$

$$r_2= \frac{d}{ds}[s^3] \bigg|_{s=-1} = \bigg[3s^2\bigg]_{s=-1} = 3$$

$$r_2 = \bigg( \frac{d}{ds} \Big[ (s-\alpha)^r ~ F(s)\Big] \bigg)~\bigg|_{s=\alpha}$$

$$F(s) = \frac{s^3}{(s^2+1)^2} = \frac{-1}{(s^2+1)^2} + \frac{3}{(s^2+1)}$$

however, if I check the result:

$$F(s) = \frac{-1}{(s^2+1)^2} + \frac{3(s^2+1)}{(s^2+1)(s^2+1)}$$

$$F(s) = \frac{-1 +3s^2+3}{(s^2+1)^2}$$

$$F(s) = \frac{3s^2+2}{(s^2+1)^2} \ne \frac{s^3}{(s^2+1)^2}$$

Why does heaviside coverup fail for this case?

I look at order of polynomial in numerator, its 3, and the polynomial order for the denominator is 4, so it should work, but it doesn't.  Does heaviside coverup method only work for first order polynomial factors?

Comment: Isn't the actual result $$\dfrac{s^3}{\left(s^2+1\right)^2} = \dfrac{s}{s^2+1}-\dfrac{s}{\left(s^2+1\right)^2}$$ So, shouldn't your expansion be different from the start as opposed to what you chose?

Comment: no idea... i haven't found a method that works yet...

Comment: $$\frac{s^3}{(s^2+1)^2} = \frac{As+B}{(s^2+1)^2} + \frac{Cs+D}{s^2+1}$$

Comment: I think numerator polynomial is one order less than denominator for expansion terms..

Comment: That looks **much** better! :-) Things like this are useful: http://www.math.udel.edu/~angell/partfrac.pdf

Comment: It's $s^2=-1$ not $s$ . Normally s should be equal to $i$ or $-i$. You can use Heaviside cover up with complex fraction though

Answer (score 2):

$$F(s) = \frac{s^3}{(s^2+1)^2}$$
Is easy to decompose:
$$F(s) = \frac{s^3+s-s}{(s^2+1)^2}$$
$$F(s) = \frac{s(s^2+1)-s}{(s^2+1)^2}$$
$$F(s) = \frac{s}{(s^2+1)}-\frac{s}{(s^2+1)^2}$$